# Unable to Create Package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a custom package in R and I have been unable to overcome this issue. I created the package using the interface in R studio It seems like as soon as I save the f

Here is my code:

```
#' Imports Multiple files from a given folder
#' @param 
#' @keywords 
#' @export
#' @examples
#' import_folder
import_folder <- function(path,skip){
  hdr <- NA
  files <- list.files(path)
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    if(substr(files[i],nchar(files[i])-3,nchar(files[i]))==".csv"){
      assign(tolower(make.names(files[i])),read.csv(files[i]),envir=globalenv())

    } else if (substr(files[i],nchar(files[i])-3,nchar(files[i]))==".txt"){
      hdr[i] <- read.table(files[i],header = FALSE, skip = if(missing(skip)){1} else {skip}, sep = "*", row.names = NULL, fill = TRUE, nrows = 1)
      assign(tolower(make.names(files[i])), read.fwf(files[i],
                                                     widths=nchar(strsplit(as.character(hdr[[i]]),"\\|")[[1]])+1,
                                                     header=FALSE,
                                                     skip=2,
                                                     row.names = NULL,
                                                     fill=TRUE),envir=globalenv())
      remove(hdr)

    } else if (substr(files[i],nchar(files[i])-3,nchar(files[i]))=="xlsx"){
      assign(tolower(make.names(files[i])),read.xlsx(files[i],sheet=1),envir=globalenv())

    } else
      print(paste("Could not read",make.names(files[i]),sep=" "),envir=globalenv())

  }
}

devtools::document()
```

However when I run the document line I get this:

```
Updating mghnywl documentation
Loading mghnywl
Updating mghnywl documentation
Loading mghnywl
Updating mghnywl documentation
Loading mghnywl
Updating mghnywl documentation
Loading mghnywl
Updating mghnywl documentation
Loading mghnywl
```

.....

which doesn't stop until times out.

I am totally lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `devtools::document()` should not be in your file; you should only call it interactively.

Comment: Also, you'll probably get several warnings about not having provided values for `@param` or `@keyword`.

Comment: @alistaire thanks! That did the trick.